# Editing <?php the_content('Read more...'); ?>

Tags: filters, hooks, the-content

Is it possible to automatically add for example image before first h2 tag in 
    the_content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You can use [`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) hook and assign your own filter to this hook.

Then you should (that is the part when things get a little bit messy) parse and replace content of that post.

So for example you can do it like so:

```
function my_the_content_filter($content) {
  $content = str_replace('<h2 ', '<img src=""...><h2 ', $content);
  return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );
```

Comment: It says error :(
Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 4 by reference in

Comment: in...? The rest of this message is important.

Comment: Parameter 4  of `str_replace` is number of replaced tokens, not number of replacement. Remove it, or use some variable here. (Cannot edit post to fix this, as "Edit must be at elast 6 charaters").